# Why does a dynamic parameter in a generic method throw a null reference exception when using an Object?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I wonder if someone could explain why in this code

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public T GenericMethod<T>(dynamic value)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

the 'return value;' statement throws an null reference exception when called with:

```
new SomeClass().GenericMethod<object>(new object()); // throws System.NullReferenceException
```

It works as expected when called with:

```
new SomeClass().GenericMethod<string>("SomeString"); // returns SomeString
new SomeClass().GenericMethod<object>("SomeString"); // returns SomeString
```

**Note**:
The following compiles and runs just fine

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public T GenericMethod<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

**The stacktrace**:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.GenerateLambda(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Visit(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.Rewrite(TypeManager typeManager, EXPR pExpr, IEnumerable`1 listOfParameters)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpConvertBinder.FallbackConvert(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
```

Comment: Nice find! Hopefully some compiler expert has an explanation.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the dynamic cast to `T` (even though the actual type is the same).  If you do `return value as T` it works as well.

Comment: The dynamic keyword tells the compiler not to enforce additional rules upon your code, which is why I think this is allowed to compile.

As for the actual return type, it looks like the value input argument holds a value, and it appears as though you can cast the value (`value as T` works, for example)

Comment: `value as T` gives a compiler error `The 'as' operator cannot be used with a non-reference type parameter 'T'`

Comment: Also changing the statement to `return (T)value;` has the same behaviour

Comment: @pvill Ah, true - I had added a `where T:class` constraint as an experiment and had not removed it.  A reference cast (`return (T)(object)value`) works without that constraint, though.

Comment: Interestingly enough, calling `AMethod<string>(new object())` results in an `InvalidCastException`, not a `NullReferenceException`.  I wonder if you found a bug in the .NET Framework runtime?

Comment: @Sam Pearson That is something I would expect. When the argument is an Object and you want to cast it to a string, an invalidcastexception is the most logical result. The dynamic keyword forces the compiler not to complain about it, but it is still thrown runtime.

Comment: It appears this bug was found in 2012, it appears it's still not fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931624/why-is-casting-a-dynamic-of-type-object-to-object-throwing-a-null-reference-exce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears [it's a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932394/1446086) first reported in 2012 but still apparently not fixed (as of May 24th 2016)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931624) indicates this is a known bug in the .NET runtime.

---

The problem is likely a poor indication of an invalid run-time cast.  If you take out the dynamic binding and make the parameter type `object` you get the compiler error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Since by adding `dynamic` this casting is done at run-time, this implicit conversion error manifests itself differently at run-time with a vague `NullReferenceException` in the run-time bindings.

I'm not an expert in the inner workings of the DLR, but I suspect that an object passed as a `dynamic` value is not *really* a pure `object` at run-time.  I suspect that it's some sort of wrapper around `object`, and thus can't be implicitly cast to object at run-time.

An explicit reference cast

```
return (T)(object)value;
```

will not generate that error.

Comment: That is correct `return (T)(object)value;` removes the error but what is the reason `return (T)value` doesn't. Why is the extra cast to (object) needed

Comment: @pvill because the same cast operator is also used to do conversions in some cases (e.g. `int i = 1; long l = (long)l;`).  It's covered in section 6.2.7 of the C# specification.  Adding the cast to object specifies that the operation is a true reference cast and not an implicit conversion.

Comment: That kind of conversion specified in that particular section should not be necessary here. `new SomeClass().GenericMethod<long>(10);` works just fine without the modification. And `value` is of type object and `T` is also Object. There should be no conversion ...